# Consuming two iterators in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Suppose I have two iterators, and I want to compute

```
fancyoperation1(iter1), fancyoperation2(iter2)
```

Normally, I would simply use `fancyoperation1(iter1), fancyoperation2(iter2)`. However, if these iterators are linked to a single source, perhaps `tee`d from a single iterator, I can't do this without keeping a lot of temporary data in memory. In that case, I know of several options:

- I could rewrite `fancyoperation1` and `fancyoperation2` into a single function that does both at the same time, but that may be a lot of code duplication, and I may not understand or have the source code for either function. Also, this would need to be done anew for every pair of operations.
- I could use threading. The synchronization can probably be written once in a helper function, and the overhead probably wouldn't be too bad as long as I don't need to switch threads too often.
- I could keep a lot of temporary data in memory.

I don't really like the drawbacks of those options, though. Is there a way to do what I want in one thread, without rewriting things or using large amounts of memory? I tried to do it with coroutines, but Python's `yield` doesn't seem to be powerful enough.

(I do not currently have this problem, but I'm wondering what to do if it ever comes up.)

Comment: A concrete example would be nice, but this is a good question.

Comment: Related, with an interesting solution using accumulate from itertools (one can also do with the accumulate from cytoolz, I don't know if this brings more efficiency): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508567/iterating-over-a-single-list-in-parallel-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can use coroutines for this, it's just slightly less convenient (but on the bright side, you can keep them separated and can leave most code unaltered). Change the fancy operations to be parameterless and repeatedly use `yield` (as expression) to fetch data instead of accepting a parameter and iterating over it. In other words, change this:

```
def fancyoperation1(it):
    for x in it:
        ...
    cleanup()

# into something like this

def fancyoperation1():
    while True:
        try:
            x = yield
        except GeneratorExit:
            break
        ...
    cleanup()
```

Of course, it's easier if there is no post-iteration clean up to be done.
You can use these like this (assuming `iter1, iter2 = tee(underlying_iter)`):

```
f1, f2 = fancyoperation1(), fancyoperation2()
f1.send(None) # start coroutines
f2.send(None)

for x in underlying_iterator:
    f1.send(x)
    f2.send(x)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: This is pretty good if I control `fancyoperation1` and `fancyoperation2`, and if they're written in Python. If they're 3rd-party code or written in C, though, this may not be so simple. I'd say keeping the code for the regular and coroutine forms of each operation synchronized would be a pain, but the regular form can just wrap the coroutine version. In any case, +1.