# Turning a generator of pairs into a pair of generators

Tags: python, tuples, generator

How would I turn a generator of pairs (tuples):

```
tuple_gen = (i for i in [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")])
```

Into two generators which would yield `[1, 2, 3]` and `["a", "b", "c"]`?

I need to process separately the first and second elements of the tuples and the processing functions expect an iterable.

The generator is very large (millions of items) so I'd like to avoid having all items in memory at the same time unless there is no other solution.

Comment: You're basically forced to use threads.

Comment: (I mean, technically, there are options that don't use threads, but they either keep a ton of data in memory or require you to rewrite the processing functions.)

Comment: No, I'm not convinced threading is necessary (or even best).

Comment: Can you guarantee they will be consumed at approximately the same rate?  If not, and your buffer is full, is it acceptable if one of the iterators blocks?

Comment: Well no, one iterator will be consumed fully before the other (since I will call the processing functions one after the other). So the tee solution doesn't cut it as it will just load it all in memory!

Comment: Can you recreate the input generator? Otherwise I don't think there's any way to do what you want.

Comment: If you can't split the data into two independent generators directly at the source, then you'll likely have to rewrite the processing code to work cooperatively.  What is the input, is that bytes coming out of a socket or something?

Comment: @wim: I edited in more info on the input.

Comment: How come generator does not fit in memory? Do you understand how generator works? From where these pairs will come? What is the point of this: `tuple_gen = (i for i in [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")])` ? It is useless/strange to create a list from an existing list! Being a generator why you do not process pairs one by one?

Comment: Is your process deterministic?  i.e., is it possible to seed the randomness and reproduce the same sequence?

Comment: Simplifying question as simple as: "Can you return twice from a function?" That would be the right way to ask.

Comment: @Elis Byberi this is obviously an example to show what I want to achieve. The generator fits in memory, this is not the point...

Comment: @antoine-sac Can you give me an explicit question? Does this question fit? **How to create two generators from the function/code above?**

Comment: You're right, I'll remove my edit which changes the question and ask a new one about how to return two generators. The question without the edit is clearer.

Comment: @wim yes I could sample twice, but this is really a waste of resources - I'd rather keep the general question without the edit and ask a separate one focusing on my particular case.

Comment: @ElisByberi This should be a clearer question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166701/several-generators-from-one-loop-returning-a-tuple-of-generators

Answer (score 3):

You can create `n` distinct iterators using the [tee](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) function from the itertools package. You would then iterate over them separately:

```
from itertools impor tee

i1, i2 = tee(tuple_gen, n=2)
firsts = (x[0] for x in i1)
seconds = (x[1] for x in i2)
```

Comment: The problem there is that consuming one of these iterators without consuming the other dumps the entire contents of the stream into memory.

Comment: Indeed, short of recreating the original generator, you would have to store the items somewhere.

Comment: –1  you ignored that requirement:  "*The generator is very large (millions of items) so I'd like to avoid having all items in memory at the same time*"

Comment: To be fair, if the `firsts` and `seconds` generators are consumed one-by-one after each other, the items would not be completely in-memory. It's only when you exhaust either one without touching the other that all the items would be stored in-memory.

Comment: ["*one iterator will be consumed fully before the other*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146905/turning-a-generator-of-pairs-into-a-pair-of-generators#comment81244989_47146905) - OP

Answer (score 1):

There's a fundamental problem here. Say you get your two iterators `iter1` and `iter2`, and you pass `iter1` to a function that eats the whole thing:

```
def consume(iterable):
    for thing in iterable:
        do_stuff_with(thing)

consume(iter1)
```

That's going to need to iterate through all of `tuple_gen` to get the first items, and then what do you do with the second items? Unless you're okay with rerunning the generator to get the second items again, you need to store all of them, in memory unless you can persist them to disk or something, so you're not much better off than if you'd just dumped `tuple_gen` into a list.

---

If you do this, you have to consume the iterators in parallel, or run the underlying generator twice, or spend a lot of memory saving the tuple elements you're not processing so the other iterator can go over them. Unfortunately, consuming the iterators in parallel will require either rewriting the consumer functions or running them in separate threads. Running the generator twice is simplest if you can do it, but not always an option.

Comment: You should discuss the possible use of `async for thing in iterable:`.  That's pretty much tailor made for this kind of use-case.

Comment: @wim: You might have more relevant experience. I haven't used `async` yet, and I'm not familiar with how you'd use async functions to handle this.

Comment: Last time I looked into this kind of thing, the best rewrite-the-consumers option seemed to be [inverting the control flow with `send`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945732/consuming-two-iterators-in-parallel). That was back before `async`.

Comment: I can't run my initial generator twice - my code is running a montecarlo simulation so running it twice is just a waste of time and electricity! I was hoping I could consume my initial generator and create two generators (that could be consumed independently of each other) in the process.

Comment: This is arguably a dupe of that, but nobody should close it because delnan's answer is somewhat outdated (2014).  There's new Python syntax allowing a cleaner implementation now.  I'll `await` the OP to update the requirements / address the comments on the question.

Comment: @wim Not sure what you are expecting me to update? Anyway thanks for the pointer, I am reading https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/ and it's very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` for operating as follows:

```
>>>from itertools import chain, izip, imap
>>>tuple_gen = (i for i in [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")])
>>>nums_gen, letters_gen = imap(lambda x: chain(x), izip(*tuple_gen))
>>>list(nums_gen)
[1, 2, 3]
>>>list(letters_gen)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

**Note**:

For **python3** `izip` would be just `zip`, `imap` just `map`

Comment: @KeiMinagawa, is there anything i did not understood from the question and that im missing? :/

Comment: This has the same problem of dumping the whole stream into memory, because the `*` in `izip(*tuple_gen)` reads the entire `tuple_gen` into a tuple. It's worse than the `tee` solution, because this dumps the stream into memory immediately, no matter what.

Comment: –1  you ignored that requirement:  "*The generator is very large (millions of items) so I'd like to avoid having all items in memory at the same time*"

Answer (score -1):

**Case 1**

I don't know where it comes from `[(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]`
But if it comes from like below code

```
gen1 = (i for i in  [1,2,3])
gen2 = (i for i in ["a", "b", "c"])
tuple_gen = (i for i in zip(gen1, gen2))
```

You can use `gen1` and `gen2` directly.

**Case 2**

If you’ve already created the list `[(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]` and just don’t want to create the list twice. You can do like below.

```
lst = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
gen1 = (i[0] for i in lst)
gen2 = (i[1] for i in lst)
```

**Case 3**

otherwise, just create one list, but it cosumes CPU resource to expand generator. This is what you don’t want to.

```
tuple_gen = (i for i in [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")])
tmp = list(tuple_gen)
gen1 = iter(tmp)
gen2 = iter(tmp)
```

I think there is no way to reset generator, iterator to first position.

Comment: Your answer was probably downvoted because your 2nd and 3rd solutions are exactly what the OP doesn't want to do. `List`s **are** fully stored in memory. Your 1st solution or at least the idea behind it would work though, if the OP could split in two the input generator, then this would solve the problem. But it's most likely not possible.