# Several generators from one loop / returning a tuple of generators

Tags: python, tuples, generator

I would like to generate two generators with one loop for computational efficiency.

My code is running a simulation where an observation is sampled (computationally expensive) and a metric computed (computationally expensive). I am interested in results where the metric meets a certain criterion.

```
def simulate(N):
    for _ in range(0, N):               # where N is typically a large integer
        obs = sampleFromSpace()         # computationally intensive
        metric = computeMetric(obs)     # computationally intensive
        if(meets_criterion(metric)):     # note the constraint on metric to filter obs!
            yield (obs, metric)
```

This code returns a generator of tuple, but what I want is a generator for the `obs` and a generator for the `metric`

Is there any way to create these 2 iterators without looping twice or storing all `obs` in a list?

Objective:

```
obs_gen, metric_gen = simulate(1e9)
```

Comment: I see what you mean, and no, you can't really do that, but you can use `zip` to unpack them.

Comment: You have to store `obs` in a list. The answer to this question is "No, you can not!" However, giving you a hint, you can store `obs` in file and load it in chunk if memory is a concern, that is fast enough. You have an up-vote from me and better delete the [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146905/turning-a-generator-of-pairs-into-a-pair-of-generators) that talks about this.

Comment: While this is distinct from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146905/turning-a-generator-of-pairs-into-a-pair-of-generators), the same problems still apply; you're not going to be able to iterate over one of these generators without storing data in memory to feed the other generator. If you can't rerun `simulate`, you'll have to store data in memory, run your consumers in separate threads, or rewrite the consumers so you can interleave their execution.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're interested in solutions which involve adding concurrency to the consumer code.  (Note: if you will iterate `obs_gen` completely before iterating `metric_gen`, or vice-versa, then what you're asking for is not possible - you're asking for magic).

Comment: In the face of overwhelming consensus, I will rewrite the consumers! Thanks all

Comment: @wim That would be a very interesting take on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166701/several-generators-from-one-loop-returning-a-tuple-of-generators)